# Using .eq() to find index of multiple Dividers with the same class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, indexing

I am wondering how to affect a certain span index within multiple divs.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/tyjaD/3/)

I have 3 Clickable Divs and 3 Span Sets within 3 other Divs like so...

**HTML**

```
<div class='clickable'>DIV</div>
<div class='clickable'>DIV</div>
<div class='clickable'>DIV</div>

<div class='spanset'>
<span>SPAN</span><br/>
<span>SPAN</span><br/>
<span>SPAN</span><br/>
<div>

<div class='spanset'>
<span>SPAN</span><br/>
<span>SPAN</span><br/>
<span>SPAN</span><br/>
<div>


<div class='spanset'>
<span>SPAN</span><br/>
<span>SPAN</span><br/>
<span>SPAN</span><br/>
<div>
```

Now this is my JQuery to affect the proper span on click (Error lies within here)

**JQuery**

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function() {

    $('span').css({'color': 'black' });

    x = $(this).index();

    $('.spanset span').eq(x).css({
        'color': 'red'
    });

});
```

It seems it is indexing the spans as a whole, not indexing them from each of their container div's (spanset class)

I am sure this has to do with this selector in JQuery

```
 $('.spanset span').eq(x)
```

Ultimately, When I click div 1, I would like the first span of each spanset to be affected, not just the first and only span on the page.

Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers here suggest using a loop, you don't need to, just use the `:eq` pseudo selector.

eg.

```
$('span:eq(' + x + ')', '.spanset').css({
    'color': 'red'
});
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4jbMg/4/)

Comment: So having html between items I would like to index is not legit? I mean, doesn't the selector decide what I am indexing...?

Comment: @VIDesignz It is legit, mistake on my part. I've edited my answer

Comment: Ok cool, I originally used the pseudo selector but assumed it should have come after the class selector .spanset span , is there a reason it ia reversed and separated with a comma? I like the simplicity of this answer, just not following the latter.

Comment: @VIDesignz this just gives the selected elements a context. So it basically grabs spans at index `x` within a `.spanset` - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context

Comment: I feel you, I guess I am  to used things like $(#id.class) where the containing element is first...this kind of throws me for a loop...could be because it's 4: 30 in the morning though...haha

Answer (score 1):

**updated version**

```
// using the loop here, instead of internally by jQuery, gives use access to the
// `.clickable`s index without recalculating it on every click
$('.clickable').each(function (n) {
  // attach the handler
  $(this).on('click', function () {
    // get all spans
    $('.spanset span')

    // reset
    .css({color: 'black'})

    // filter the elements using `n` from the outer scope, profiting from
    // native implementations for `nth-child`
    .filter(':nth-child(' + (2*n + 1) + ')') // the used formula depends on the
                                             // actual markup. This one accounts
                                             // for the <br /> tags
    // apply new styles
    .css({color: 'red'});
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CcM2K/

**old version**

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function () {
    // get the index of the clicked element within it's parent
    var clickedIdx = $(this).index();

    // reset all span elements (could also use removeClass(), hide(), ...)
    $('.spanset span').css({
        color: 'black'

    // get only those spans that have the same index within their parents
    }).filter(function (idx) {
      // for this we use the spans index in the complete list, get the modulo of
      // that index and the index of the clicked element
      return idx % 3 === clickedIdx; // the literal 3 should be the number
                                     // of total clickable divs. If that number
                                     // is subject to change, a count here or in
                                     // the parent scope would be appropriate.
    // apply new css to only those filtered spans
    }).css({
        color: 'red'
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ntTJA/1/

Comment: + 1 Very well explained, much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the `each` function of JQuery :

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function() {

    $('span').css({'color': 'black' });

    x = $(this).index();

    $('.spanset').each(function(spanset){
        $(this).children().eq(x).css({
            'color': 'red'
        });            
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/oxilik/1/edit)

```
$('.spanset').each( function(){
    $(this).children('span').eq(x).css(...)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you didn't properly close the spanset's div tags. change them all from `<div>` to `</div>`.

and this is another way:

```
$('span').css({'color': 'black' });

x = $(this).index();
$('.spanset').each(function(){
    $('span',this).eq(x).css({
       'color': 'red'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use `:nth-child()` selector

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function() {  
     /* $(this).index() won't work due to clickable has more siblings than just clickable*/  
      var idx=$('.clickable').index(this)
    $('.spanset span:nth-child('+(idx+1)+')').css({
        'color': 'red'
    });

});
```

API Reference    http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this http://jsfiddle.net/tyjaD/33/

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function() {

$('span').css({'color': 'black' });

x = 2 * $(this).index() + 1;

$('.spanset span:nth-child(' + x + ')').css({
    'color': 'red'
    });

});​
```